# Python IndexError:invalid index to scalar variable

Tags: python, physics

I've already looked through previous questions on the issue but I can't seem to solve it. I am trying to solve an equation with time dependence (Somewhat irrelevant) but I keep getting "invalid index to scalar variable" errors for line 31. That is when I define b in the nested loop. I appreciate your help. My Python is rusty as I've been been primarily working with Fortran recently

```
def main():
#Constants
    hbar= 1.0534*10**(-34)
    m=9.11*10**(-31)
    dx=0.1*10**(-9)
    dt=1*10**(-15)
    M=[[]]
    b=[[]]
    psi=[[]]

#Wave function definition    
    x=np.linspace(0,10,100)
    psi[:]=sp.exp(-(x-3)**2/4)/((2*np.pi)**(0.25)*(1*10**(-9))**0.5)
    n=len(x)

    r=(hbar*dt/(2*m*(dx**2)))*1j   

#Matrix eigenvalues for diagonals and off-diagonals    
    for i in range(1,n-2):
        for h in range(1,n-2):
            if i==h: 
                M=2*(1+r)
            elif i==h+1 or i==h-1:
                M=-1*r

    for k in range(1,1000):
        for q in range(1,n-2):
            b=2*psi[q+1][k]+r*(psi[q][k]-2*psi[q+1][k]+psi[q+2][k])
        matmul=np.transpose(np.inv(M)*np.transpose(b))
        psi=np.transpose([0,matmul,0])
    psi=np.transpose(psi)


main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what all your code is looking to accomplish, but you're hitting an error here because you are treating `psi` as if it is a list of lists (by calling psi[q][k], the *k-th* element of the *q-th* element of psi), when in fact it is a list of scaler/floats. You can add a `print psi` statement before the line that is breaking your code to verify this. I get:

```
psi = [2105.1955756978987, 2443.3566356290821, 2821.4068271041683, 3241.3729378382568, 3704.9020343410039, 4213.1691313503734, 4766.7842561936268, 5365.70...
```

Comment: Alright. I have fixed that now and gotten rid of other lists of lists since they are meant to be 2-D matrices.